# What is it called when someone substitutes a picture of an object or a symbol for a name?

Tags: terminology

What is it called when someone designates/substitutes an object or symbol for a name (or even a word)?

In this example, it's a red blob, which someone has called an "ID". ID is normally used for "Identification document"; is it the customary term for a graphical screen name?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: These are usually called "icons" http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/icon

Comment: As I see it, "ID" seems to be used as textspeak for "idea" in this example (similar to "m8" for "mate"), not referring to ID as "identification".

Comment: Apparently, this person wants to know what we call graphical substitutes for words (I'd say 'emoji', and was writing that answer when this got put on hold). This is especially clear with the image. Separately, it seems the OP is wondering what 'ID' means in an online setting. It does not mean 'idea', as @Flater suggested, but rather 'identification', as it always does. In this case, 'ID' is short for 'user ID' which is analogous to user name...

Comment: ...further, the 'clever ID' in this screen grab is 'Idiot Above'. 'Idiot Above' is replying to a comment made by '<red ball emoji>'.

Answer (score 1):

'Avatar' might be appropriate but also 'emblem' or 'logo', in some cases, or 'rebus' for a pictorial representation of a word.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/avatar
"2  An icon or figure representing a particular person in a video game, Internet forum, etc.
‘conversation is depicted in a balloon over the avatar's head’"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emblem
"An emblem is an abstract or representational pictorial image that represents a concept, like a moral truth, or an allegory, or a person"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo
"a graphic mark, emblem, or symbol commonly used by ... individuals to aid and promote instant public recognition"

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rebus
"1.1   historical An ornamental device associated with a person to whose name it punningly alludes."

Comment: As per my comment on another of your answers, we expect dictionary definitions and citations/links to where you found the definitions, when supplying suggested words as an answer. Highly voted answers on this site tend to be well researched.

Comment: Please transfer the relevant parts of external sources into your answer. The citations are necessary, but answers should be complete in themselves.